# using an Anaconda environment without source activation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow

i installed Tensorflow on ubuntu using the tutorial presented in the website. it was installed successfully meaning that when i run :

```
source activate tensorflow
```

in my terminal and then do :

```
(tensorflow) $python
import tensorflow
```

everything works fine. i was wondering if there is a way to make the python interpreter understand and import tensorflow without the need to activate the environment i created previously?
meaning that i simply open the terminal and run my python code containing tensorflow objects?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply install tensorflow without anaconda environment.
Just type 
pip install tensorflow (make sure you have deactivated any environment). From now on you will be able to use tensorflow without activating any environment.

Comment: Thanks , that did work , but i meant is there anyway to introduce the conda installation to all scripts , as other conda packages that were installed without using an Environment are usable by default.